# Is there an equivalent of the Java equals method in c++?

Tags: c++, variables, comparison

Is there something like Java `equals()`? To compare if object is the same type ?

```java
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof ViewMode)) {
        return false;
    }
    
    ViewMode dm = (ViewMode) obj;
    return dm.width == w
        && dm.h == h
        && dm.b == b
        && dm.f == f;
}

public int hashCode() {
    return w ^ h ^ f  ^ b ;
}
```

Comment: I removed the `java` tag because a Java expert cannot help answer this question.

Comment: It's been a long time since I wrote any C++ but I think that you'll have to overload the == operator.

Comment: The tabs were messing up your formatting. So I fixed it for you.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6767423/5740428

Answer (score 15):

For the idiomatic equivalent of your example, you would define `operator==` as follows:

```
friend bool operator==(const ViewMode &lhs, const ViewMode &rhs) {
    return (lhs.w == rhs.w) && the rest;
}

friend bool operator!=(const ViewMode &lhs, const ViewMode &rhs) {
    return !(lhs == rhs);
}
```

In C++ you don't normally write a function to allow `ViewMode` objects to be compared with something that has nothing at all to do with `ViewMode`. I suppose that if you really wanted that comparison to return false, rather than refusing to compile, then you could add a couple of template operators (as free functions, outside the class):

```
template <typename T>
bool operator==(const ViewMode &, const T&) {
    return false;
}

template <typename T>
bool operator==(const T &, const ViewMode&) {
    return false;
}
```

but I really don't recommend it. That Java idiom doesn't apply to C++, because in C++ you pretty much should never have an object, but have no idea of its type.

If you want your equals function to be virtual, then it's probably best to write an `equals()` virtual function, rather than using `operator==` for it. You'd write it to take a `const ViewObject &` as parameter, so no need for any equivalent to the `instanceof` check. Which is just as well, because C++ does not have any way to take an object of totally unknown type and test whether it is an instance of a specified type.

You rarely need a polymorphic equals function in C++, but if you were using it for example in `std::unordered_map`, then you'd specify the extra template parameters to the `unordered_map`. Give it an equality comparison function that takes two pointers and calls `equals` on one or the other, and a hash function that does something sensible.

Comment: Good call, I'd forgotten that.

Answer (score 13):

No. C++ does not have a global type model like Java. There is no `Object` type from which all other types inherit, so there are no methods (like `equals`) that are defined for all classes.

C++ provides a framework for building a type model with a universal comparison operation: `operator ==`. It is up to you to build out all of the implementations of this in all of your classes so that they interact correctly. But there is no default implementation comparable to `Object.equals`.

Comment: As a further note, idiomatic C++ *typically* does not require downcasting from a base class as much as Java.

Comment: "there are no methods (like equals) that are defined for all classes" - you could make a case for unary `operator&` ("address-of") being defined for everything, but that's just pedantry ;-)

Comment: While there is no root `Object` class in C++ language itself, one should note that multiple C++ frameworks **do** have a root object class. Examples: `Object` in MFC, `QObject` in Qt, `wxObject` in wxWidgets, `BaseObject` in our own ALF framework.

Answer (score 5):

You can define the `operator==` in your class.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) operator for this.