# How to represent irregular, but ordered, data in objects?

Tags: c++, binary-data

I have a set of files with binary data. Each file is composed of blocks and each block has a header and then a set of events. Each event has a header and then a sequence of fields. My problem is with the sequence of fields.

These fields contain different lengths of ordered/structured data but the fields do not come in any particular order. For example, in one event I might have in one event 3 fields looking as follows:

```
Event Header (12 bytes, always, made of things like number of fields, size, etc)
Field Header (2 bytes, always, field type in the top 4 bits, size in the bottom 12)
Field Data   (4299-4298(VDC) data, Signals from various wires in a vertical drift chamber)
Field Header ( '' )
Field Data   (ADC-LAS data, Signals from various photo multiplier tubes)
Field Header ( '' )
Field Data   (FERA data, Signals from a fast encoding readout adc system)
```

In another event I might have the same fields plus a few more, or a field removed and another added in, etc. It all depends on which pieces of the DAQ hardware had data to be recorded when the readout system triggered.

I have thought about a few possible solutions and honestly, none of them seem palatable to me.

**Method 1:**
Make an abstract base class `Field` and then for each field type (there are only 13) inherit from that.
*Pros:* Reading the data in from the file is easy, simply get the region id, allocate the appropriate type of field, read the data, and store a `Field*`. Also, this method appeals to my sense of a place for everything and everything in its place.
*Cons:* When I process the fields in an event to convert the data to the information that the analysis actually uses I am continuously needing to `dynamic_cast<>()` everything to the derived class. This is a bit tedious and ugly and I remember reading somewhere (a while ago) that if you are having to use `dynamic_cast<>()` then you are using polymorphism 'wrong'. Also this makes having object pools for the fields tricky as I would need a pool for every subclass of `Field`. Finally, if more field types are added later then in addition to modifying the processing code, additional subclasses of field need to be created.

**Method 2**:
Simply have a big array of bytes to store all the field headers and data. Then leave it up to the processing code to extract the structure as well as process the data.
*Pros:* This means that if data formats change in the future then the only changes that need to occur are in the event processing code. It's a pretty simple solution. It's more flexible.
*Cons:* Jobs in the processing/reading code are less compartmentalized. Feels less elegant.

I recognize that there is probably not a solution that is going to be 'elegant' in every way, and from the standpoint of KISS I am leaning towards method 2. **Should I choose Method 1, Method 2, or is there some Method 3 that I have not thought of?**

Comment: It depends to a reasonable extent what you want to do with the data once you have read it in. Is speed of reading / access critical to you or flexibility in processing? Will you need to search the data? Store it? Forward it on, or act on it somehow? The answers to these questions should direct your solution.

Comment: After the processing step the raw data has been converted to 'useful' values for the analysis. Position on the focal plane, scattering angle, energy deposited in scintillator detectors etc. After processing those 'useful' values are forwarded so they can be placed into a ROOT tree for future use. So the storage / access is handled elsewhere and I don't need to search it. I guess that slants things even more towards Method 2 but that is just my interpretation.

Comment: Here is some information for working with multiple derived classes.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547379/avoid-dynamic-cast-with-derived-classes-cast-derived-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to choose between struct or tuple or MSRA safeprotocole handler

`    // Example program
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    #include

```
// start ABI Protocole signature
const int EVENT_HEADER_SZ = 12;
const int FIELD_HEADER_SZ = 2;
const int FIELD_DATA_SIZE = 2^12;
// end ABI Protocole
#ifdef WINDOWS
#define __NOVT __declspec(novtable
#else
#define __NOVT
#endif 

struct Protocole_Header __NOVT {
    union {
       char pbody[EVENT_HEADER_SZ+1];
       unsigned ptype    : 32;
       unsigned psize    : 32;
       unsigned pmisc    : 32;
    };
};
struct Field_Header __NOVT {
    union {
        char    fbody[FIELD_HEADER_SZ+1];
        unsigned ftype   : 4;   // type of data 0...15
        unsigned fsize   : 12;  // size of field data to follow up 0..4096 max size
    };
};
struct Field_Data {
    std::string _content;
};

typedef std::tuple<uint_fast32_t, int_fast32_t,uint_fast32_t> Protocole_Header2;
enum PHR{
    TPL_TYPE,
    TPL_SIZE,
    TPL_ETC
};

std::istream& operator >>(std::istream &is, std::tuple<uint_fast32_t, int_fast32_t,uint_fast32_t>& tpl)
{
   is >> std::get<TPL_TYPE>(tpl) >> std::get<TPL_SIZE>(tpl) >> std::get<TPL_ETC>(tpl); 
    return is;
}


union Field_Header2 {
    char    fbody[FIELD_HEADER_SZ];
    unsigned ftype   : 4;   // type of data 0...15
    unsigned fsize   : 12;  // size of field data to follow up 0..4096 max size
};


int main()
{
  Protocole_Header ph;
  Field_Header fh;
  Field_Data fd;

  long i;
  char protocole_buffer[FIELD_DATA_SIZE+1];

  std::cin.get(ph.pbody,EVENT_HEADER_SZ);
  std::cin.get(fh.fbody,FIELD_HEADER_SZ);
  for(i=0;i<ph.psize;++i) 
  {
    std::cin.get(protocole_buffer,fh.fsize); 
    fd._content = protocole_buffer; // push somewhere else 
    std::cin.get(fh.fbody,FIELD_HEADER_SZ);
  }
// ... 


// ...
    Protocole_Header2 ph2;
    Field_Header2 fh2;
    std::cin >> ph2;
    std::cin.get(fh2.fbody,FIELD_HEADER_SZ);
    for(i=0;i<std::get<TPL_SIZE>(ph2);++i) 
    {
        std::cin.get(protocole_buffer,fh.fsize); 
        fd._content = protocole_buffer; // push somewhere else 
        std::cin.get(fh2.fbody,FIELD_HEADER_SZ);
    }
}`
```

Here , you have both of your answer ...

Note , using metastructure over structure is as much a burden than find back the code and recompile it in case of rupture of protocole.
Usually you do not define ABI for protocole structure, and that why C++ Spirit was made.

A parser must be used to handle protocole ( always, because protocole is a grammar on its own, define a EBNF and your code will run for decades without people to recompile it ... )

There is only exception for not using a parser , its when you need to pass MSRA or Heatlh Care or any Regulated sector. Rest of time, don't bind external data to ABI structure with C or C++ , it's a 100% cause of bugs .

Comment: What is MRSA safe protocol in this context? I know what MRSA is in terms of infections, but that does not make sense in this context.

Comment: Just to make certain that I am understanding what you are saying correctly, let me try to summarize. Parsing the data structure yourself is error prone, instead define a context free grammar, feed the grammar to Boost:Spirit (or similar) and use that to parse the data. I can agree with this in principle, but then I am still left a few questions. What if the field data format changes (because of detector hardware replacement/addition)? How well does Spirit handle purely binary data (which needs byte swapping)? Also, how would I get the parsed data to processing functions?

Comment: If data format change you won't parse , so no execution to worry about until you add more grammar to follow change.

Comment: You still didn't answer what you meant by MRSA safe protocol.

Comment: Hi, MSRA is a platform to test a program and certify it's compliance agaisnt certain rule ( for heatlth care, avionic , etc... )